# “My birthday is not even for 3 days.” - what does this sentence mean?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, colloquialisms

> My birthday is not even **for** 3 days.

This sentence is from a movie. How is it interpreted for native speakers?

As I know, the preposition "for" usually if time is related means during. 
So I thought that the duration of birthday is 3 days. but in reality,
it is impossible that a birthday is more than one day.

Others say that the meaning of above sentence is like three days away from the moment speaker is telling.

I want to know a general approach to the interpretation in detail.

Please, help me.

Comment: It's probably a paraphrase of 'It's not even my birthday for three days.'

Comment: Is the above sentence often expressed? It's not easy for me to interpret since there is no verb and the subject is not a person.

Comment: My guess is: X acted as though today was Y's birthday, but Y is telling X that X was three days early.  "My birthday is not even for 3 days."

Comment: GEdgar - it seems to me that your guess is the most plausible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The use of 'for' seems idiomatic and an abbreviated form of 'for another'. Native speakers would understand it to mean 3 days from now (in the future).

Comment: No mention of the phrase's ambiguity? Some people (notably D-list celebs)  celebrate their landmark birthdays for a week, so the speaker could be saying petulantly that their birthday lasts less than three days.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think anyone would expect that interpretation without something like "being celebrated for". Even if someone does celebrate their birthday over a long period, they wouldn't say "my birthday is for a week".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Another example: "Chanukkah lasts 8 nights", but we don't say "Chanukkah is for 8 nights".

Comment: @Barmar note, I did use the verb "last" in my comment, I just wanted to nudge Ross into giving a fuller answer, that's all.